# "Capture full size screenshot" in Brave or Chrome doesn't work on certain pages (such as Airtable)

Tags: google-chrome, screenshot, brave

I *love* the "Capture full size screenshot" feature built into Chrome and Brave and use it frequently.

However, it seems that certain websites are coded in a way that the "Capture full size screenshot" feature does not know how to handle. And so then the resulting screenshot does not contain the full scrolled length of the page.

An example I've run into multiple times is long forms on https://airtable.com.

I'm wondering if there is some workaround; perhaps I could open the DevTools panel and adjust a certain element's HTML or CSS before pressing "Capture full size screenshot".  Although it would be annoying to need to do this, I really don't want to install extensions.

Comment: *"I'm wondering if there is some workaround"* -- Just a thought, but have you tried scrolling to the bottom of the page with these problem pages? Personal experience, but this is the issue I've encountered most often (i.e. certain portions of the page are loaded via JavaScript, but only after scrolling).

Comment: @Anaksunaman Thanks for the suggestion. Yep, I tried that already, but it didn't help.

Comment: Use this Chrome extension instead it uses many tricks to ensure optimal results https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gofullpage-full-page-scre/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl

Comment: You can use https://recorder.easeus.com/screenshot.html to capture full size screenshot with good quality images and I found It very helpful.

Answer (score 10):

I found a really helpful answer [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1304526)*, which worked!

I opened DevTools and added this CSS rule before running "Capture full size screenshot":

```css
html, body, div, section {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Another person on that page also mentioned:

> Note that you can also use a JavaScript bookmarklet to toggle this style rule.
>
> `javascript:/*style::toggle*/(function(){var L='s-overflow',S='html,body,div,section{overflow:visible!important;}',SS,E=document.querySelector('style[id="'+L+'"]');if(E){E.parentNode.removeChild(E)}else{SS=document.createElement('style');SS.setAttribute('type','text/css');SS.id=L;SS.textContent=S;document.querySelector('head').appendChild(SS)}})()`

Update on 2021-09-15: I just tried that JavaScript bookmarklet when a page at notion.site was giving me trouble, and the bookmarklet fixed the problem (and "Capture full size screenshot" then worked correctly).

*2021-10-09 Update: Actually, I decided to add `,  section` too since sites like LinkedIn use that tag.

Comment: I have noticed that capturing full-size screenshots also doesn't work with scaled SVG files, and this trick doesn't appear to resolve it.

Comment: Here's instructions how to add the CSS rule in Chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54613970/1317406

Answer (score 3):

[@Ryan's solution](https://superuser.com/a/1674437/325412) worked for me, but sometimes it breaks the layout since the `div` (and `section`) selector is quite broad.

To fix this:

1. Open the DevTools and select the element (or the scrollable area) you want to screenshot (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> on macOS /
   <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> on Window, hover over the
   particular element on the page and click it)
2. Go to the Console tab of the DevTools
3. Paste the code below into the Console, and
4. Press Enter <kbd>⏎</kbd>

```js
var elem = $0;
while (elem) {
  elem.style.setProperty('overflow', 'visible', 'important');
  elem = elem.parentElement;
}
```

> This code will add the `overflow: visible !important` style attribute only to the relevant node and all of its parents.

Then capture a full size or node screenshot (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on macOS / <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on Window, and search for `screenshot`).

Comment: This worked for me rather than the CSS one.